# При запуске веб-приложения появляется ошибка Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, mvc

**Exception**
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

**Root Cause**
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'coffeeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void app.controller.CoffeeController.setCoffeeService(app.service.CoffeeService); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'coffeeService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'bookDao' while setting bean property 'CoffeeDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class app.dao.CoffeeDaoImpl
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

**Пример для контроллера**

```
package app.controller;

import app.model.Coffee;
import app.service.CoffeeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class CoffeeController {
    private CoffeeService coffeeService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "coffeeService")
    public void setCoffeeService(CoffeeService coffeeService) {
        this.coffeeService = coffeeService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "coffees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listCoffee(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("coffee", new Coffee());
        model.addAttribute("listCoffee", this.coffeeService.listCoffee());

        return "coffees";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/coffees/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addCoffee(@ModelAttribute("coffee") Coffee coffee) {
        if (coffee.getId() == 0) {
            this.coffeeService.addCoffee(coffee);
        } else {
            this.coffeeService.updateCoffee(coffee);
        }

        return "redirect:/coffees";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public String removeCoffee(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        this.coffeeService.removeCoffee(id);

        return "redirect:/coffees";
    }

    @RequestMapping("edit/{id}")
    public String editCoffee(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("coffee", this.coffeeService.getCoffeeById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listCoffees", this.coffeeService.listCoffee());

        return "coffees";
    }

    @RequestMapping("coffeedata/{id}")
    public String coffeeData(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("coffee", this.coffeeService.getCoffeeById(id));
        return "coffeedata";
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<web-app xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" version="2.4">

    <display-name>Coffee Shop</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="app"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Database Information -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url"
                  value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="ВАШ ПАРОЛЬ"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>app.model.Coffee</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--BookDao and BookService beans-->
    <bean id="bookDao" class="app.dao.CoffeeDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="coffeeService" class="app.service.CoffeeServiceImpl">
        <property name="CoffeeDao" ref="bookDao"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="app"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>CoffeeShop</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CoffeeShop</name>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Hibernate -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Logging -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.15</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Servlet -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Test -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.7</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!--PostgreSQL-->
              <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                      <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <finalName>CoffeeShop</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Ну и ссылка на гит, если чего то не хватает: https://github.com/MaratMukhutdinov/CoffeeShop.git
Не нашел на форумах ответа на этот вопрос.

Comment: `Error creating bean with name 'bookDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class app.dao.CoffeeDaoImpl` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная ошибка вот эта:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter cannot be cast to java.util.logging.Logger
```

Вы падаете вот в этой строчке:

```
private static final Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(CoffeeDaoImpl.class);
```

когда пытаетесь прикастовать логгер из пакета `slf4j` к логгеру из пакета `java.util.logging.Logger;`, уберите кастование, сделайте импорт на логер вот так:

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

и будет счастье.

Опционально:
В контроллере уберите у аннотации @Autowired параметр `requared`, по умолчанию он итак true, Idea это вам бы наверняка подсветила. Уберите `@Qualifier` , это аннотация используется тогда, когда для одного и того же типа зависимости, есть несколько вариантов реализаций и вы стремитесь устранить неоднозначность, говоря явно, с каким id бина нужно связать данный компонент, в Вашем случае неоднозначности нет, реализация интерефейса `CoffeeService` у вас одна и спринг автоматически свяжет с ней. Не используется @Autowired, это небезопасно и тем более через `setter`, просто создайте конструктор со всеми вашими сервисами в параметрах, спринг автоматически заинжектает зависимости. Также и в сервисах, и в xml-кофиге зависимости на заинжектуемые бины вы уже будете подавать не через `property` а через `constructor-args`
Когда вы инжектаете зависимости через конструктор, в случае если если какая то зависимость не подтянулась вы упадаете на этапе компиляции, в случае с `setter-injection` это будет `Runtime`.

Comment: Спасибо, убрать кастование и правда решило проблему, однако теперь появились некоторые другие ошибки:org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException, org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException